# Get consecutive date ranges from overlapping date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been trying all sorts of things and I can't figure this out. I haven't seen an identical problem in my searches.

I have a table with multiple date ranges, and I need to get the ones that are consecutive, and not overlapping. For example:

Table:

```
Company | StartDate  | EndDate
---------------------------------
A       | 2014-07-01 | 2015-06-30
A       | 2013-07-01 | 2014-06-30
A       | 2013-01-01 | 2013-12-31
A       | 2012-07-01 | 2013-06-30
A       | 2012-01-01 | 2012-12-31
```

Desired Result:

```
Company | StartDate  | EndDate
---------------------------------
A       | 2014-07-01 | 2015-06-30
A       | 2013-07-01 | 2014-06-30
A       | 2012-07-01 | 2013-06-30
```

We essentially have fiscal years and calendar years here. I want my result set to be based on the most recent set of dates. Since the most recent ones are 7/1 - 6/30, I don't want any 1/1 - 12/31 ranges in the results. I can't just hard code anything like `WHERE MONTH(EndDate)=6` because in real life, the fiscal year beginnings and ends can vary considerably. I can't do `EndDate + 1 = StartDate` because the old calendar year will make the new calendar year fit into that set.

I have limited access to this DB, so I can't write SPs or temp tables. This is for SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Include your original table(s) and include your current query.

Comment: I don't understand why can't you use enddate+1 = start date. can you explain that again?

Comment: 2012-12-31 + 1 = 2013-01-01, so the row with the 2013-12-31 end date doesn't get excluded.

Comment: will the month/day always be the same for the consecutive dates?

Comment: Does this table have ID?

Comment: No. I've been trying some things with `ROW_NUMBER()` to get around that. The only other field that might be helpful is a time stamp, but there is no guarantee that the date range I want was time stamped before or after the date range I don't want in a given year. So, I'm pretty sure I already have the relevant fields in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Based from your statement,
"Since the most recent ones are 7/1 - 6/30, I don't want any 1/1 - 12/31 ranges in the results."

I assumed this  is your basis in what you want as a result.

```
SELECT MAX(StartDate) AS MostRecentStartDate
      ,MAX(EndDate) AS MostRecentEndDate
FROM myTable
```

Use this as your inner query and join with your table. Only those with matching `Month` of `StartDate` and `Month` of `EndDate` will return.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable AS tb
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(StartDate) AS MostRecentStartDate
           ,MAX(EndDate) AS MostRecentEndDate
     FROM myTable
     ) AS src
ON MONTH(tb.StartDate) = MONTH(src.MostRecentStartDate)
AND MONTH(tb.EndDate) = MONTH(src.MostRecentEndDate)
```

Comment: That's a pretty good thought. Unfortunately, I have a few date ranges like `2011-12-27 - 2012-12-31`, which messes with the results.